# Data speed on usb 1.0 vs 2.0

Tags: usb, internet-connection, 3g, usb-2, mobile-broadband

I have a CDMA USB dongle that I use for connecting to the internet. Now I plan to upgrade to a 3G dongle which has a USB 2.0 connection. Right now I have only USB 1.0 port on my computer.

Will the internet speed vary depending on whether I connect a 3G USB internet dongle to USB 1.0 port or a 2.0 port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3G adapter would be limited to the maximum rate of a USB 1.0 port (12 Mbits/s) when attached via one.

Answer (score 0):

Not practically.  According to [this link](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080615115623AA2w0Fh) Wideband CDMA has a maximum speed of 384Kbps.  USB1 is rated at up to 12 Megabits/second.   You might get a fractionally higher speed because of lower latency, but it won't be noticeable.

Comment: I wanted to get that information wrt a 3G dongle which supports upto 21 mbps speed which is more than 12 mbps limit of USB 1. Sorry if I have misunderstood your response.

Comment: HSPA+ runs at 168 MBit/s peak. The 384 kbps limit applies only to the oldest 3G networks.